# adb2c remember username and password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

We have custom policies with KMSi support. We have a requirement to store username/password to on client's browser so that once KMSI is expired, user dont have enter username/pass.

Is there a way to support this?

Thanks

Comment: This seems work for a password manager.

Answer (score 0):

Only the user can choose to do that if their browser supports it.